# Passing Information Between Output Blocks in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I have a Shiny program that functions, but is extremely slow and cumbersome because I call compute-intensive functions repeatedly in each output block.

While this works, it takes minutes to run because I am forcing the computer to repeatedly calculate the same information each time it needs it.

How can I do a single function call, pull the resultant data into a single list, then distribute it to the various Shiny output blocks that need different parts of it?

Here is the server side code that works... (I think the ui side is ok...)

```
library(shiny)
 shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
  output$table7 <- renderTable({
  inFile <- input$file1   
  if (is.null(inFile))
  return(NULL)   
  WorkingSet <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=TRUE, sep=',', 
                      quote='"')  
  TempHolder <- CARTOptimizer(WorkingSet, input$seed, input$k, input$whichcluster)
  TempHolder$v2
})
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
  inFile <- input$file1
  if (is.null(inFile))
    return(NULL)
  WorkingSet <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=TRUE, sep=',', 
         quote='"')
  TempHolder <- CARTOptimizer(WorkingSet, input$seed, input$k, input$whichcluster)
  clustertree = rpart(badcluster ~ ., data=TempHolder$v3, method="class",
         control=rpart.control(cp=TempHolder$v1))
  prp(clustertree)
})
  output$table1 <- renderTable({
  inFile <- input$file1
  if (is.null(inFile))
  return(NULL)
  WorkingSet <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=TRUE, sep=',', 
             quote='"')
  SingleClusterHolder <- SingleCluster(WorkingSet, input$seed, input$k,
    input$whichcluster)
  SingleClusterHolder$v1
 })
})
```

Screenshot of Shiny Output:

[image: screenshot of Shiny output]

Note that CARTOptimizer and SingleCluster are user defined functions that return three different values each:

- CARTOptimizer$v1 = Best cp value for CART analysis
- CARTOptimizer$v2 = Confusion Matrix
- CARTOptimizer$v3 = Refined Data Set with Additional Columns for Subsequent Analysis
- SingleCluster$v1 = Matrix on Cluster Details
- SingleCluster$v2 = Refined Working Data Set (factors stripped)
- SingleCluster$v3 = Refined Holding Data Set (factors present)

As you can see, some of these are single values, some are matrices, and some are data frames.

Suggestions on how to make this more efficient would be greatly welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you have 3 entities that need to be updated: table7, table1, and plot1.  I think that the best think you could do here is to remove as much code as possible from the functions that assign those.  For example, it looks like you load the same csv file 3 times, once for each output.  You should have a separate reactive block of code that reads the file and assembles whatever information it needs from that file without producing any graphs.  To prevent it from causing the other functions to execute, use a `return(NULL)` condition in each output that prevents display if the other parameters haven't been set.  If results from the same function are used in more than one output, have that function be a separate reactive object.  Then, whenever a parameter is changed in the UI, that function executes once.  The fact that its results have changed then trigger the associated outputs to change.

In general, if you are putting the same computationally intensive code into your `server.R` file multiple times, you are creating a slower program.  Find a way to have the updates occur like dominoes, so that each variable to be updated in response to a change in input is held in its own reactive object and stored in a variable.  Then use those variables only where necessary in the definitions of your outputs.